# Top options for onboarding web2 user into web3 (creating a wallet, sign transactions, etc.)

Tags: web3js, wallets, dapps

I am working on a dApp POC where users can log in using their existing web account(google sign-in, username\password, etc.) and would be prompted to create a new web3 wallet. What are some of the most user-friendly options available for allowing users to transition from web2 to web3 seamlessly? Thanks!